# Given set of points, how to approximate a rectangle using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a set of points as shown in the image attached. How can i approximate a rectange or draw a rectangle using these points?

The easiest will be to get min(x) and min(y) as top left and max(x), max(y) as bottom right, but that wont solve for any anamolous point. here is sample data to try with:

```
[(569, 800), (569, 272), (404, 801), (404, 274), (624, 801), (624, 273), (457, 800), (457, 277), (516, 800), (516, 273), (686, 800), (686, 272), (681, 801), (681, 271), (343, 274), (352, 801), (399, 801), (399, 274), (349, 273), (341, 795), (442, 801), (442, 274), (462, 800), (462, 277), (415, 274), (433, 801), (411, 801), (420, 274), (431, 274), (451, 800), (451, 274), (676, 791), (344, 279), (676, 279), (347, 801), (356, 275), (483, 800), (342, 790), (676, 801), (473, 277), (344, 319), (667, 324), (346, 364), (667, 364), (347, 405), (664, 411), (345, 447), (666, 452), (387, 801), (387, 276), (347, 490), (654, 496), (409, 275), (342, 627), (655, 621), (342, 620), (666, 539)]
```

[image]

Comment: Which point in your image is anomalous? Your suggested min/max approach would surely work fine here?

Comment: Is your rectangle always *"axis-aligned"*, i.e. not oriented at an angle?

Comment: You cannot draw a rectangle matrix You can use `cv2.polylines`. Here is image https://imgur.com/a/vw5JwUK

Comment: @MarkSetchell This image doesn't have any anomaly but in some case a point may be at the corner of the image.

Comment: The rectangle can be rotated slightly in some cases.

Comment: Please share an image with an anomalous point and a rotated one so we know what we have to work with.

Answer (score 1):

> how to approximate a rectangle ?

Let's solve a simpler problem:

> how to approximate a polygon ?

Answer: throw a
[convex hull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html#scipy.spatial.ConvexHull)
around the input points.

Now you have far fewer points to worry about.
And you have a handful of `y = m x + b`
straight line segments to consider. (Or prefer
[parametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#Parametric_equation)
form, to side-step the issue with slope of a vertical line.)

Line segments which nearly touch and which have
nearly equal slopes can be merged into a single segment.

For each line segment you can compute
[MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error)
for its nearby points, and
consider adjusting the line with a technique like
[OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares)
to put the line more nearly in the center of those points.

---

Now that you have cleaned up the input points
to form an irregular pentagon or whatever,
we can worry about the original problem.

We're looking for four 90° angles, and
two pairs of parallel segments with end points
that could become rectangle corners.
Search for "small angle" vertices
that let us merge segment pairs,
till you find an "almost" rectangle or give up.

Perturb the corners slightly so we have a perfect rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for the input, i will try and code this algorithm.